# Global Variable in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am trying to use global variable in Scala. to be accessible in the whole program .

```
val numMax: Int = 300 

object Foo {.. }
case class Costumer { .. }
case class Client { .. }
object main {
var lst = List[Client]
// I would like to use Client as an object .

}
```

I got this error :

> error: missing arguments for method apply in object     List;
>       follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially   applied function
>                   var lst = List[A]

How can I deal with Global Variables in Scala to be accessible in the main program .
Should I use class or case class in this case ?

Comment: With your code comment, it's not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want a globally accessible, mutable list of `Client` objects? Or do you want to have a single globally accessible `Client` instance that you want to put in a list?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a global variable thing. Rather, you want to say this:

```
val lst = List(client1, client2)
```

However, I disagree somewhat with the other answers. Scala isn't just a functional language. It is both functional (maybe not as purely as it should be if you ask the Clojure fans) and object-oriented. Therefore, your OO expertise translates perfectly.

There is nothing wrong with global variables *per se*. The concern is mutability. Prefer `val` to `var` as I did. Also, you need to use `object` for singletons rather than the `static` paradigm you might be used to from Java.

Comment: global variables makes programs more difficult to test

Comment: That statement is broad and oversimplified. You need to look at the context of how it's used, the size of the program, the details of the language/platform, and so on. Try to avoid broad platitudes in software development. That said, if you can do the same thing without a global variable, then do it. But it isn't quite as black-and-white as you make it seem. Obi-Wan said it best: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgpytjlW5wU

Comment: It's also somewhat oversimplified to say that the concern is just mutability. The scope of a mutable variable makes the difference between a functional program (e.g., a local variable in a referentially transparent function) and a programming nightmare (i.e., a global variable). That said, it's not even clear whether the OP meant global *variable*. He may have meant global *value* and just doesn't have the terminology yet.

Comment: While interesting, those are nuances I did not address because 1) they are tangential to the OP's question, 2) this isn't the place for theoretical computer science discussions, and 3) Stack Overflow frowns upon long opinion threads. I am happy to address these points in a more appropriate venue like Twitter. I would also mention though that the original question had a `var`. I just really hope you aren't one of those people who fights with his girlfriend on Facebook. There is a time and place for those lengthy discussions, and it isn't an online thread.

Comment: noticed the `var`, but the code comment makes it sound like he's possibly trying to treat a `Client` as a singleton value. It's not entirely clear. Props for trying to answer anyway, though.

Comment: Hopefully the OP will take all our comments into consideration, learn the advantages and disadvantages of all the approaches, and make the best decision for his or her situation.

Answer (score 1):

The error you quote is unrelated to your attempt to create a global variable. You have missing `()` after the `List[Client]`.

If you must create a global variable, you can put it in an object like `Foo` and reference it from other objects using `Foo.numMax` if the variable is called `numMax`.

However, global variables are discouraged. Maybe pass the data you need into the functions that need it instead. That is the functional way.

Comment: Can you recommend other links ! I am coming from OOP world !

Comment: Coursera has an [excellent introduction](https://www.coursera.org/course/progfun) to functional programming in Scala.